# Texture painting is totally messed up, resulting in lines and unpainted areas

Tags: texture-painting, artifacts

after a few hours of hairpulling trial end error I ended up more confused than before. I am not extremely familiar with all that blender has to offer, however I decided to take the task of modelling something for my game. I am trying to make a spaceship corridor, but whenever I try to paint on the walls that are extruded from the floor plane, Blender paints weird angles and artifacts, and I have no clue what is wrong. If there is anyone who knows what causes this, help would be greatly appreciated. I even considered separately painting every part and then combining the textures, but I refuse to think that there is not an option I am missing that has to do with my issue.
[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: Did you make UV-map?

Comment: What UV projection did you use? Did you unwrap using 'Smart Project' or just default 'Unwrap'?

Comment: First of all you should make sure that you don't have overlapping faces (select one, grab it, look at the result, Esc to cancel).

Then if you have no or some kind of autogenerated UV map, it might be possible that your wall face only has a tiny bit of space (e.g. one pixel) in the UV map. That means that Blender can not accurately calculate the color for a certain texel on that face.
You should check if it's alright by going into edit mode of your object, and opening the UV editor (separate window), then select your texture if not already and have a look at the map.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by using the smart uv project once I finished the layout of the corridor. I am currently working on figuring out the best settings to paint the cubes and planes without them appearing to be imperfectly colored. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, turns out my Uv maps were messed up totally.